# How to filter case-insensitive in a JTable

Tags: java, regex, swing, tablerowsorter

i try to filter my JTable with this code:

```
String eingabe = eingabeF.getText();
RowFilter.regexFilter(".*" + eingabe + ".*", 1)
```

it works very well. BUT i want to filter it case-insensitive. All the values in my Column "1" have upper-cases at the beginning.

I tried this:

```
String eingabe = eingabeF.getText();
setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(("?i") + Pattern.quote(".*" + eingabe + ".*"), 1));
```

but i always get the following Error-message:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-3" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Dangling meta character '?' near index 0
?i\Q.*f.*\E
```

Comment: It is `(?i)` not `?i`. you must add parenthesis.

Comment: Why not writing :`RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i).*" + Pattern.quote(eingabe) + ".*", 1)`

Comment: das lässt sich hören!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the embedded case insensitive flag is `"(?i)"`, rather than `("?i")`. Secondly, you do not need to put `".*"` around your string. The matcher will find it anywhere within the field as long as you do not surround it with `"^"` and `"$"`. It is much simpler to initialize the filter as follows:

```
RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + eingabe, 1);
```